# prove the following compact result about $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$:

prove for any $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (endowed with Euclidean topology),there exist some neighborhood $U(A)\subset GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ near $A$ and some compact set $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$(which only depends on choice of $A$) . such that $U(A)K$ always contains in $F$.

My attemp since $\{A\}$  is compact in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$,there always exist some $U(A)$ as neiborhood of $A$ that is relative compact in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$.We only need to show for set of relative compact matrix if acts on compact set $K$ it is still contains in compact set.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen A typo,we need to show $U(A)K \subset F$ for some $F$ for the given $A$ and $K$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U(A)=\{B\in GL(n,\mathbb R)\mid \frac{||A||}{2}<||B||<2||A||\}$, where $||\cdot||$ is the operator norm.

($U(A)$ is open follows from the fact that all norm on $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ are equivalent.)

Let $R=\max\{||x||\mid x\in K\}<\infty$.

Then $||Bx||\leq ||B||\cdot ||x||\leq 2||A||\cdot  R$ for all $B\in U(A)$ and $x\in K$.

Take $F=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid ||x||\leq 2||A||\cdot R\}.$

Comment: Should open implies by continuous of nrom?

Comment: thanks  I got it since for finite dimension space operator norm topology homeomorphic to the euclidean topology hence $U(A)$ also open in Euclidean topology correct?

Comment: @yili Yes. The (euclidean) topology you mean, is just the topology induced by norm. And equivalent norm induces the same topology, that is the open sets are the same.

Comment: @yili I guess what you mean is $f:A\mapsto A$,  $(\mathbb R^{n\times n},||\cdot||_2)\to(\mathbb R^{n\times n},||\cdot||)$ is a heomeomorphism.

Comment: yes,thanks $\ \ \ \ $